# Filtering tagged blog posts using intermediate table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I am trying to render a page by filtering the articles by tags. I want the related articles to be displayed when a user clicks the tag in All-articles.html

Im not sure how to go about it or how I would write the code.

Should I create a path in `urls.py` like
`path('tag/<str:tagslug>', views.tag, name='tag'),`
so that I can access the url within the `views.py`?

How would I write the ORM to filter articles by tags in `views.py`?

Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks

`models.py`

```
class ArticleTags(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Articles', models.DO_NOTHING)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tags', models.DO_NOTHING)

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=75)
    tagslug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default=None)

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    metatitle = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_created', blank=True, null=True)  
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')
```

`views.py`

```
def allarticles(request):
    articles_list = Articles.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(articles_list, 12)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {'page_obj': page_obj}
    return render(request, "All-articles.html", context)
```

`All-articles.html`

```
{% for article in page_obj %}
    <article>
      <div>
        <img
          src="media/{{ article.cover }}"
          alt="menu item"
          class="article-photo"
        />
      </div>
      <header>
        <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
      </header>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could begin by setting it up so when the user clicks the tag, it sends the tag name to the server via POST request. You could then filter the articles via the tag name and return the new context to the template.

The problem with this is you will have a page refresh unless you do it via AJAX or use `e.preventdefault()`

If you're going to have multiple actions on one page that requires HTTP requests, I would strongly recommend avoiding page refreshes.

When the user selects a tag, make an Ajax request like so:

**All-Articles.js**

```
function myAjaxRequest() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your route to the function in views.py (if its the same page, this 
        will be an empty string)',
        data: {filter: yourTag}
    })
}
```

Then use the tag to filter your data and return via Json Response.

**views.py**

```
def allarticles(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
       tag = request.POST['filter']
       *Now just use the tag to filter your model.*
       data = serializers.serialize('json', MyModel.objects.filter(field_name=tag))
       return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Finally, take the response and insert it into your HTML where it belongs. You will get the response from the return of your AJAX call in your Javascript file.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have a direction to work towards now. I tried the stuff you mentioned and am getting a POST 403 forbidden error. Can you tell me how I would fix that and also how I would render the data in HTML?

Comment: Do you have the console open when you are getting this error so you have more context? On Chrome, right-click, inspect, click the console tab and run the operation again. It should give you more clarity as to what is throwing the error. Are you passing a CSRF token?

Comment: The error context on console is something like this `jquery-3.6.0.min.js:formatted:3919 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/all-articles 403 (Forbidden)`.
Sorry Im a noob in web development, by passing CSRF token you mean
writing {% csrf_token %} in all-articles.html? I have done that but if there's more to CSRF token please let me know.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the html file?
I have little confidence that this is right..

`<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %} {% for i in all_tags%}
<p>{{ i.tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</form>`

Comment: If you're using Ajax, you need to pass the CSRF token in the data parameter via AJAX. Django template language won't work here. There are lots of resources available explaining how to do this...

Comment: Hey @rastawolf, I tried using the csrf_exempt and I think it solved the 403 error, but now Im getting a 500 internal server error. I've opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776553/post-500-internal-server-error-using-ajax-in-django