# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) using AJAX in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-models, django-views, django-ajax-selects

I hope someone can help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to filter the blog articles by tags, so that certain articles are render in  `all-articles.html` when the user clicks on the tag.

Any help is appreciated!

Below is the error I get in the console with the context.

[image]

Error in Terminal

`/Users/haashe/Documents/Projects/LensTok/lenstok-main/django/lenstokyo_backend/blogapp/views.py:30: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'blogapp.models.Articles'> QuerySet. paginator = Paginator(articles_list, 12) Internal Server Error: /all-articles Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/haashe/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-FSWjPP8U/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner response = get_response(request) File "/Users/haashe/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-FSWjPP8U/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/haashe/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-FSWjPP8U/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view return view_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/Users/haashe/Documents/Projects/LensTok/lenstok-main/django/lenstokyo_backend/blogapp/views.py", line 39, in allarticles data = serializers.serialize('json', Articles.objects.filter(field_name=tag)) AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'serialize'`

`All-articles.html`

```
<div class="tag-nav-links">
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %} {% for i in all_tags%}
      <p>{{ i.tag }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </form>
</div>
```

`app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tag-nav-links").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "",
      data: { filter: `${e.target.textContent}` },
    });
  });
});
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework import serializers

@csrf_exempt
def allarticles(request):
    articles_list = Articles.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(articles_list, 12)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    all_tags = Tags.objects.all()

    if request.is_ajax():
        tag = request.POST['filter']
        data = serializers.serialize('json', Articles.objects.filter(field_name=tag))
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

    context = {'page_obj': page_obj, 'all_tags': all_tags}
    return render(request, "All-articles.html", context)
```

`models.py`

```
class ArticleTags(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Articles', models.DO_NOTHING)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tags', models.DO_NOTHING)

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=75)
    tagslug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default=None)

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    metatitle = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_created', blank=True, null=True)  
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="cover", blank=True, default='logo-00-06.png')
```

Comment: Can you post the internal server error that you are getting? It will display in the terminal you are using to run `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Oh there are a couple of errors! I've edited the question with the error in terminal.

Comment: Start by importing these...
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

Comment: Hey I think Im almost there, this time it gave me the below error. 
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'field_name' into field. Choices are: articletags, cover, field_created, id, metatitle, slug, summary, title

Can you help me out with field_name part in views.py?

Comment: 'field_name' is the field that you should filter on. Replace 'field_name' with the name of the field you wish to filter on in your model.

Comment: @rastawolf , it took me a while but I finally managed to fix the errors. Sorry for the noob question, but how do I render it into html now? Could you explain the final part ? "Finally, take the response and insert it into your HTML where it belongs. You will get the response from the return of your AJAX call in your Javascript file."